# Convert a varchar to datetime including hour minute and seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a date column that is in varchar. I need to convert it to datetime format.

> My data looks like this in varchar:29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM
>
> I want this to be in datetime format like this: 29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM

I am using following query:

```
select convert (datetime, (convert (float, [KYC_STATUS_CHANGED_DATE])),120) from [dbo].[KYC_Data_31122012]
```

But it is giving following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why a varchar for a date column ?

Comment: Why two `CONVERT`s? You say you have data saved as `VARCHAR` and want it to be `DATETIME` yet you first convert `VARCHAR` to `FLOAT` and then that to `DATETIME`, seems like the "inner" `CONVERT` is too much maybe? Furthermore the format you mention is only relevant for displaying, a `DATETIME` is a saved point in time with no format included, that only becomes relevant when you want to display it again.

Comment: Is `DateTime` even that precise? From MSDN: `datetime  values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`. You can't parse that string unless you strip off some of the subsecond precision. SQL will only recognise 3 digits after the seconds

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Converting varchar directly to datetime results this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Charleh: I need only up to seconds. Do not need to be that much precise.

Comment: [Use 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: @SadatMainuddin If that conversion fails, that indicates that your format is wrong (as others have pointed out as well) see this page for accepted formats in sql-server http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: When I use `:` as time separator and use just 3 digits after the second, the convert works. So use some `substring` magic to cut off some of those digits.

Comment: To add to that you should first consider how those dates enter your database. Can you control that? Would be better than having to do replacing on datetime-varchars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the whole hog and do a replace/substring to get your answer

```
select cast(Replace(SUBSTRING('29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM', 
0, len('29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM') - 9),'.',':') as datetime)
```

Ugly but it works!

Comment: It works. However this also trims off the AM and PM. I need those.

Comment: Well, unless your date is using a 12 hour clock, you don't need to worry about AM/PM. Storing the data is different from displaying the data. The data in SQL is stored as a numeric value (an offset from a particular base-date) - to display AM/PM you need to use a date formatting function. However it looks like the hour part of your date is 12 hours so you would need to take the last part of the date and add 12 hours if the value is PM (you will also need to make sure the value wraps correctly). The question I'm getting to is, why do you have dates as varchar?

Comment: I had to import the data from a notepad. The data has " (double quote) as text identifier. So I had to upload it as varchar.

Comment: Ok so parse out the last 2 characters (you can use a `CASE` statement) - `CASE WHEN RIGHT('date string', 2) = 'PM' THEN Some Logic ELSE some other logic END`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried. But can not do it. Can you please help me with the code? 

PS: Thanks for your tremendous help though. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a date column that is in varchar.

Wrong in the first place. You should use the datatype created for the data.

> I need to convert it to datetime format.

If you're using ASP.NET (I am guessing by the sql-server usage) then you can use this:

```
var time = Convert.ToDateTime("some_time");
```

However

> My data looks like this in varchar:29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM
>
> I want this to be in datetime format like this: 29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM

What do you think that this might be? I don't see this as a time. Its a combination of Time and some String for me.

> Error converting data type varchar to float

You are converting varchar to float, float is a datatype for decimals. Floats have a floating decimal between their numbers. So I think that you're not converting the varchar to datetime, instead you're writing a code to convert it to float.

Instead of in SqlServer select, try converting it in the page like I did.

> 29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM

In this thing, where is ':'? Server won't guess that it has any time in it. You should try to convert the datatype to datetime in the first place!

Good luck, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

your date format is wrong

the correct format is something like

```
29-JUL-11 02:44:29.985 PM
```

and isnt

```
29-JUL-11 02.44.29.985 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the datetime if you restrict the precision for the milliseconds for 3 digits.

```
set @str = '29-JUL-11 02.44.29.984664000 PM'
select cast(Replace(SUbSTRING(@str,0,len(@str)-8) + SUBSTRING(@str,len(@str)-2,len(@str)),'.',':') as datetime)
```

Comment: Same problem. When I try to run it through a column it says: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Did you trim the milliseconds to 3 characters?

Comment: @SadatMainuddin I have updated the Answer to get a more suitable answer. Please feel free to ask if you have any issues.